# C for R programmers - recommended resources/approaches once past the basics

Tags: c, r

I would like to improve my C skills in order to be more competent at converting R code to C where this would be useful. What hints do people have that will help me on my way?

Background: I followed an online Intro to C course a few years ago and that plus *Writing R Extensions* and *S Programming* (Venables & Ripley) enabled me to convert bottleneck operations to C, e.g. computing the product of submatrices (did I re-invent the wheel there?). However I would like to go a bit beyond this, e.g. converting larger chunks of code, making use of linear algebra routines etc.

No doubt I have more to learn from the resources I used before, but I wondered if there were others that people recommend? Working through examples is obviously one way to learn more: Brian Ripley gave a couple of examples of moving from S prototypes to S+C in this workshop on [Efficient Programming in S](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/bdr/Washington98/) and a more recent Bioconductor workshop *Advanced R for Bioinformatics* (sorry can't post hyperlink) includes a lab on writing an R+C algorithm. More like this, or other suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have struggled with this issue as well.

If the issue is to improve command of C, there are plenty of book lists on the subject. They all start with K&R. I enjoyed "Expert C Programming" by P. van der Linden and "C primer" by S. Prata. Any reference on the C standard library works.

If the issue is to interface C to R, other then the aforementioned official R document, you can check out this [Harvard course](http://www.stat.harvard.edu/ccr2005/), and this [quick start guide](http://www.stat.umn.edu/~charlie/rc/). I have only passed scalar and arrays to C, and honestly wouldn't know how to interface complex data structures.

If the issue is to interface C++ to R, or build C++ skills, I can't really answer as I don't use much C++. A good starting point for me was "C++ the Core Language" (O'Reilly). Very simple, primitive, but useful for people coming from C.

Comment: I'm selecting this answer as it seems most relevant to where I am now. The Harvard course will be useful to revise C, introduce me to C++ (see comment to Dirk's answer) and is focused on using C/C++ in R.

Answer (score 20):

That is a very interesting question. As it happens, I had learned C and C++ before moving to R so that may have made it "easier" for me to add C/C++ to R.

But even with that, I would be among the first to say that adding pure C to R is hellishly complicated because of the different macros and R-internals at the C level that you need to learn.

Which leads me to my favorite argument: Use an additional abstraction layer such as the [**Rcpp**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) package.  It hides a lot of the nasty details.  And I hope that you don't need to know a lot of C++ to make use of it.  One example of a package using it is the small [**earthmovdist**](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/earthmovdist/) package on R-Forge which uses 
[Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) wrapper classes to interface one particular metric.

*Edit 1:* For example, see the [main function of earthmovdist here](http://r-forge.r-project.org/plugins/scmsvn/viewcvs.php/pkg/src/emdL1_R.cpp?rev=14&root=earthmovdist&view=markup) which should hopefully be easy enough to read, possibly with the (short) 
[Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) wrapper classes package manual at 
one's side.

*Edit 2:* Three quick reasons why I consider C++ to be more appropriate and *R-alike*:

- using [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) wrapper classes means you never
  have to use PROTECT and UNPROTECT, which is a frequent source of error and heap
  corruption if not mapped
- using [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) and with STL container classes like `vector` etc means you never have to explicitly call `malloc()` / `free()` or `new` / `delete`which removes another frequent source of error.
- [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) allows you to wrap everything in `try` / `catch` blocks at the C++ level and reports the exception back to R --- so no sudden seg.faults and program deaths.

That said, choice of language is a very personal decision, and many users are of course perfectly happy with the lower-level interface between C and R.

Comment: This is interesting - not something I'd considered. Your arguments are quite convincing, but I've not looked at C++ at all before, so would need to do a bit of homework first.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with C/C++, but I inherited a package that uses C, and I gather that C++ is somewhat backward compatible with C - is that the case? Is it easy / worthwhile to migrate C->C++ just to take advantage of Rcpp?

Comment: At a first approximation, C++ is a superset. So you can take advantage of Rcpp to maintain the existing C-based packages.

Answer (score 9):

My primary recommendation is to look at other packages.  Needless to say, all packages don't use C code, so you will need to find examples that do.  You can download the source code for all packages off CRAN, and in some instances,  [you can also browse them on R-Forge](http://r-forge.r-project.org/).  [Some R projects are also maintained on Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:R) or sites like github ([for instance, ggplot2](http://github.com/hadley/ggplot2)).  You will find the C code in the "src" directory.

- [Here's an example of a src directory with some C source code on R-Forge for the "survival" package](http://r-forge.r-project.org/plugins/scmsvn/viewcvs.php/pkg/survival/src/?root=survival).
- [Here's an example with C source code on Google Code for the "rpostgresql" package](http://code.google.com/p/rpostgresql/source/browse/#svn/trunk/RPostgreSQL/src).
- [Here's an example with C source code on github for "rqtl"](http://github.com/pjotrp/rqtl/tree/master/src/).

In general, think about what you're trying to accomplish, and then look at packages that do similar things.

The "C Programming Language" book is probably still the most widely used, so you may want to have that on your bookshelf.  The following free book is also a useful resource: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/

Comment: I just randomly clicked http://github.com/pjotrp/rqtl/blob/master/src/fitqtl_hk.c link you provide to novice. Do you think that using ***p is good way to start? Does R have pointers

Comment: Well it makes sense to learn from those who have trod a similar path (even if their code may not be the perfect example).

I've got a copy of K&R (2nd ed) which used to be my Dad's - nice to know it's still considered useful :)

Answer (score 3):

"What is the best book to learn C?" is a [perenial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422648/any-good-online-c-book) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464287/i-want-to-learn-c-closed).  (The middle link is probably the best.)

As for R-specific ways of learning C, I've found it instructive to download the R source code and take a look at some the .Internal code.

**EDIT:** Someone else had just asked ["What to read after K&R?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426544/what-to-read-after-kernighan-ritchie)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to use C to get rid of bottlenecks you'll need a good numerical library in C.  There are lots, but I've found gsl (GNU Scientific Library) pretty useful.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

There is also the classic book "Numerical recipes in C" which provides an overview of important numerical techniques (though I don't recommend using their code verbatim).

Comment: I'm not sure how useful this is in my case. I am writing code for R packages and I think using gsl code would mean that my packages would require users to have gsl on their computer? I'd prefer only to depend on code distributed with R (or available via CRAN). Correct me if I'm getting this wrong!